# My question was deleted, can I get the infomation/answers from it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I had a question that was closed and subsequently deleted. I understand why it was closed (subjective), but it had some really good career advice on it that I haven't had chance to read through and take in. I'm not particularly bothered if the question stays deleted! I just want the information from the answers/comments on the question. Is it possible to get the information back?

Question: "What to Learn??" on Stack Overflow
. Question number: [1890322](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890322/what-to-learn).

Comment: Hints on the title?

Comment: Needlepoint is good to learn.

Comment: I don't currently see a "What to Learn" or anything like it in the 10k tools list of recently deleted questions (on Stack Overflow), so I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for trying. It may have been deleted a few days ago I only noticed when I tried to read reposes to my question earlier!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here:

http://semiaxis.com/wtl/what-to-learn.htm

It's just a copy of what I can see.  Don't expect that copy to be around on the above site for long though.

Comment: That was fast, isn't up any longer.

Comment: Thank you very much.. copying it now! sorry cant up-vote not made it to 15 yet.

Comment: Since you have it, I've removed it from my website - I didn't scrutinize the file for unintended consequences to the website, so I can't leave it up permanently.