# OP removed question after I posted an answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540608/django-1-5-cannot-find-the-defined-view-when-using-templateview/15541075#15541075) only to come back later and find that the OP had removed it.

Is there anything I can do about this - I took the time to answer the question, it was a valid (if simple), question - It doesn't seem right that the OP can remove it my answer.

Is there any way I can reinstate it?

Comment: OK, I really did look for this duplicate before posting - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108683/people-deleting-their-own-questions-once-they-have-an-answer?rq=1

Comment: Looks like the OP found out this wasn't his true problem and didn't see any point leaving the question be. You think the question had value to other people? If so let us know here and three 10K+ users can undelete the question for you. (Or one mod)

Comment: The question contains a valid and specific problem. There were only a limited number of possible solutions and I provided 2 in my answer. The question contained code and and a stack trace - the cause of the OP's error was unambiguous. If phrased correctly (I don't remember), the question would be helpful for other users (it was an an issue of import statements and namespaces in python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've happily voted to un-delete it. If you could edit the question so that it was not as localised as it is currently (My Djano knowledge is albeit *sparse*) then that would make it more useful.

As it stands, you're waiting on 1 more vote to undelete, I'm sure it won't be *too long* until someone else votes too :).

**EDIT: It's open!** Now edit it to make it less localised so it can help others too.

**I also upvoted you so it can't be deleted by the OP**

I suppose we could say, Django Unchained? (*I'll get my coat ;)*)

[image]

Comment: Check it now. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Magic!

Comment: FYI, Django was named after jazz guitarist Django Reinhardt.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Not true, Django was named after a Unicorn, you of all people should know that! Clues in the logo :) http://pravaltirubeni.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/pink_mascot.jpg?w=300&h=150

Comment: Thanks Mattytommo. OP has made it more complicated by editing her own question in a way that changes it's meaning - she's corrected her original coding error, and changed the exception output by the stacktrace! (admittedly her new error did exist in her code, but it wasn't causing the original exception). Now my answer just looks silly becuase it doesn't relate to the question as it stands. OP has added her own answer.

Comment: @AidanEwen Oh dear, another example of a Chameleon question. I hate those! Unfortunately, there's nothing we can do about that one :(

Comment: Well, thanks again for your help @Mattytommo