# Can users delete questions after getting an answer

Tags: discussion

[How to statically limit function arguments to a subset of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527226/how-to-statically-limit-function-arguments-to-a-subset-of-values/20527381?noredirect=1#comment30691688_20527381)

That just disappeared and the OP had a good question, he clearly has the capacity just not the knowledge, it suddenly disappeared and the OP has no questions showing on his page.

Is that bad? It doesn't feel good? (I'm not sure what to make of it)

Comment: See also: [User quickly deletes own question once they have received an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178570)

Comment: The first sentence of your answer sounded very unsure. The rest wasn't really relevant to what was being asked. And in your comments you wouldn't give a firm answer, but told me to *'google "Go enum"'*. So I did and found a more solid answer. That sounded like an abandonment to me, and it led me to a duplicate, so I deleted it.

Comment: @user2736012 you shouldn't have, SO isn't running low on the few kb it took to store it :P You had a good thought process leading up to it, anyone else in your boat would have to reinvent the wheel unless they find that question. The question is important but the reason for posing it is not worthless!

Comment: @user2736012 additionally, that sounds like a tick to me it got you there :)

Answer (score 1):

We don't want users to delete their question simply because they got an answer, that is correct.  This is why having questions deleted shortly after they were asked is a very significant contributor to the question ban; if this behavior continues and the user doesn't have other positive contributions then the user is likely going to be banned from asking further question.

Comment: And that user will never know why, this is where an inbox for "private messages" would be great, something where I could tell him "hey that was a good question" or "careful, that's a bad habit"

Comment: @AlecTeal There have been a number of proposals for that over the years; you can look them up yourself to see why they won't be implemented.