# Deleting others' work

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently a question was posted on MathOverflow, which received (I think) more than an average number of upvotes. There was an answer to the question, by someone other than the OP. Next day, the question was deleted by the author (without me seeing any reasons for that), and the answer got thereby deleted as well. I then looked at the OP's page, and he seemed to have gotten a "Disciplined" badge for this action!

It does not seem right to me when a person can so easily delete others' work. Moreover, this seems to contain a serious potential for abuse. E.g., it is easy for one to get an email account, open a new MathOverflow account with it, post a question, get an answer, then delete both, and retain and use the undocumented answer.

I am not sure what would be the best way to deal with this problem. I know that, e.g., once a paper appeared on arXiv, it may be withdrawn but never deleted (as I recall, arXiv says it is done in the interests of good scholarship). Of course, SE's goals and operating model are different from arXiv's.

Yet, I think something should be done to prevent the OP from being able to delete others' work, whether in answers or comments.

Perhaps, more radically, deletions may be abandoned altogether **(with poor, inappropriate questions to be placed into some special places, such as the bottom of the list, or into specially labeled folders)**.

---

I posted the above question, "Deleting others' work", on MathOverflow Meta ([Deleting others' work](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2834/deleting-others-work)), but then I realized that this problem concerns the entire SE. The question "Deleting others' work" received an answer and some comments on MathOverflow Meta on how to alleviate the problem, but no complete solution to it was provided. That is, no answers were given to these **main questions: (i) Why should the OP ever be allowed to delete others' work? and (ii) More generally, why can't deletions be abandoned altogether and replaced by other measures, such as the ones I suggested?**

(I am aware of related, but different questions on SE Meta sites, such as the one at [I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question) .)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented

Comment: A related proposal of mine over on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315406/19679 . We need to be able to delete bad content (because there sure is a lot of it), but I'm for limiting someone's ability to delete questions once they've received any kind of answer. Askers are already prevented from deleting questions when an answer has been upvoted, but I'd like to see that extended to account for the presence of any answer.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211145/can-users-delete-questions-after-getting-an-answer

Comment: rene: I am familiar with this content. However, in the case I briefly described the question (and thus the answer) seemed to be removed very quickly, before the answer had a chance to receive upvotes.

Comment: Brad: I am glad you are for "limiting someone's ability to delete questions once they've received any kind of answer." As for deleting "bad content", why not put it instead in a "bag" labeled "junk" or something perhaps less offensive? Good content may not always be immediately recognized.

Comment: @IosifPinelis At its base, deleting on SE _is_ just placing content into a bag labelled "junk", with the added feature that access to this bag is limited. Except in rare instances, all deleted content can be undeleted.

Comment: arjafi: why limit access to that bag? That only creates a big hurdle to get " deleted content [...] undeleted", as specified in my comment to Patrick's answer.

Comment: I think this question would fare better if you decoupled wanting all deletions to stop from preventing/slowing deletions of questions shortly after they receive an answer that has not had time to gather its first upvote. I would vote for the latter but not the former.

Comment: PolyGeo: I agree with you, in that the second part of my question/suggestion is substantially more radical than the first one. However, I believe that a junk bag (vs. deletions) is the simplest and most effective general solution. As I mentioned, arXiv has a never-deleted policy (even the authors can only withdraw, but not delete their postings), and that policy seems to work well.

Comment: @IosifPinelis You limit access because otherwise you're just shuffling the crap around, and Stack Exchange becomes a storehouse for this crap. The current situation might make it more difficult to have non-crap undeleted, but lower rep users still have ways to seek help in this: flagging for moderator attention, site chat rooms, and site metas. Also, sufficiently privileged users have access to a list of recently deleted posts.

Comment: @IosifPinelis arXiv also has more restrictions on who can post articles there. If you have more trust in the users who are posting to the site, then there is less of a need for deleting content. There are virtually no restrictions on SE, which makes it much easier for crap, or just worthless stuff, to be posted, which necessitates deletion in order to keep quality up. Note that viXra, with very few restrictions on who can post articles, reserves the right to "reject" submissions.

Comment: If you are wedded to your "junk bag" idea, then maybe you can focus this question on that, and start a new question focussed solely on preventing/slowing deletions of questions shortly after they receive an answer that has not had time to gather its first upvote.  That way you may be able to recover some of the lost reputation from this question.

Comment: @PolyGeo : Thank you for your advice. It appears that the junk (or supposed junk, or the outcome of abuse) is stored by SE anyway, and so, the main question boils down to this: who has immediate access to the (deleted posts)/(junk bag): everyone or just the 10K people? It looks like 10K people decided that it's a burden rather than a privilege to have that access, and they take that burden upon themselves. I think it would be better if everyone was allowed to decide for themselves, whether to access that bag or not.

Comment: *If an answer to your question is acceptable to you, you can formally accept it by clicking on the check button at the upper left corner of the answer. That would give 15 points to the answerer and 2 points to you*

Answer (score 10):

Deletion itself isn't the problem: the user abusing that possibility for something that is against the goal of the site is.

Deletion of a mediocre question without good answers is something we want to encourage : we want quality, right.

That a user deletes his question shortly after receiving an answer, not giving it the time to gain upvotes is. (If it stayed for a day or two and then didn't receive positive votes, I guess it is okay to delete)

What you can do now: flag a post of your. Explain in the custom flag reason why you think OP is abusing the deletion option. Give it some time and see if the mod agrees (maybe it was just a mediocre answer to a mediocre question, then the mod would keep it deleted)

I would propose to disallow deletion of a question when it just received an answer, maybe set the threshold to a day or so.

Comment: You too are talking about abusers of the system. But the thing is that the system can be easily changed to prevent such abuse. "Deletion of a mediocre question without good answers is something we want to encourage : we want quality, right." Of course, we want good quality. So, why not put questions that seem poor into some kind of junk bag, instead of deleting?

Comment: What is the benefit of keeping them?

Comment: One of the benefits is that the quality can be rather easily misjudged (except in some obvious cases), and it's important to keep a chance to re-evaluate it. Also and perhaps more importantly, replacing deletions with the junk bag provision will eliminate the kinds of abuse discussed in the above comments.

Comment: There is a delete and undelete list for high reputation users. They can undelete stuff and actively review that list.

Comment: Patrick, I know about that. But why prevent the rest from possibly benefiting -- especially from maliciously deleted answers?

Comment: The point is: only useless material should he deleted.

Comment: A "useless" judgment is subjective and prone to error. Why not a junk bag instead?

Comment: Deleted posts can be undeleted, so there is no use in relabeling it. It is already there.

Comment: And we don't want *any* user to see junk posts hanging around. If they have value they can be resurrected.

Comment: Patrick, I don't think it's quite correct. To undelete a post, one first has to remember enough about it to identify it (most potential users may not have have any idea about the deleted post); then one has to write to moderators, then moderators have to approve such a request. That is a rather tall order.

Comment: No. As said there is a list available to 10K users. They can review those posts. Additionally you as a post owner can flag it. You will still have it in your browser cache.

Comment: There are rather few 10K users; what about the rest of us? Also, how can I flag a post deleted by someone else (except again what I said in my last comment to your answer).

Comment: Those are 'lucky' they don't have to deal with so much crappy posts. Flag any post and link to the deleted post.

Comment: I don't think that those whose work is deleted by a malicious OP feel lucky. Also, how do I link to the deleted post that I cannot see?

Answer (score 1):

Can't see any issue here.

Once there is more than one answer, or the single answer has a positive score (1 or more net votes) the OP can't delete the question anymore.

So if there is only one answer, with score of 0 or less, this usually means the answer isn't that great, hence no real loss in it being deleted.

Comment: I agree but you do know there are  users that delete within minutes after receiving an answer. Those answers don't have a fair chance to collect that single up vote ...

Comment: @rene that's true, and can be seen as abusing the system - such users should be flagged, and if they keep doing it, suspended.

Comment: My suggestion would simply prevent such abuse. Also, don't you think that it's just wrong to allow the OP to delete others' work (especially an answer to their question), of whatever merit the OP may judge it to be?

Comment: @IosifPinelis no I think it's totally fine and greatly helps to remove bad stuff - users who realize they were way wrong, and there's no point keeping the question around anymore.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Your suggestion would prevent a small amount of abuse that already has a lot of tools in place to prevent and/or mitigate it, and would prevent the deletion of lots of content that *we don't want here* without leaving any real recourse to deal with that problem.  That would cause way more harm than good.

Comment: @Servy : why "without leaving any real recourse"? It's the junk bag vs. deletions. Where is the harm? (Thanks to ShadowWizard -- should I drop the space in your ID for a notification?)

Comment: @IosifPinelis The harm is lots of very poor quality content, making the quality content harder to find, and the potentially significant amounts of time and effort that will be wasted by people going to the question and reading it when they didn't need to, or spending time and effort trying to moderate the content.

Comment: @Servy : When you have junk in a so-labeled junk bag -- why would it be "making the quality content **harder** to find"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Because you'd flooding the site with literally *millions* of entirely worthless posts.