# Is this the place for programming for PLD chips?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a mechanical engineer buddy who does some programming for PLDs (Programmable Logic Devices). From my years here at SO, it's obvious to me that the languages asked about on SO are geared towards higher level devices like computers or cell phones; devices with processors and that are a little more Von Neumann-esque. Is there a different StackExchange site more oriented for these lower level devices and projects?

Comment: There was a Controls Stack Exchange, but it's been disabled.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** There are [several programmable logic device questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=programmable+logic+devices) on Stack Overflow. You can either ask it here or on the [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=pld) site.  There are a few questions and you'll more likely get a response.

On a side note I wish [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98192/stack-exchange-various-site-organization-and-map/98251#98251) was implemented.

Comment: Sorry about the original post, I searched **pld** on SO and missed the results.