# My question got deleted at Stack Overflow, can I still find it somehow?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted)
>   [My question was deleted, can i get the infomation/answers from it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33540/my-question-was-deleted-can-i-get-the-infomation-answers-from-it)

Can I somehow find [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610697/why-would-a-web-developer-choose-mac-os-over-windows-linux) I asked and which got deleted over Stack Overflow? I didn't backup the question, and it was quite long, and I've found a more relevant place to ask it in.

Found the URL from my History, but it just shows me a 404. If they truly get pruned completely, it's really really wrong. :/

If someone with high reputation is able to access the deleted question, messaging me the contents would be very nice and save some time.

Comment: Weird, I thought OP can see his own deleted posts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think that's true for posts that the OP deletes voluntarily.

Comment: @Chris IMO think OP should always see - but it's not the topic here. red - please don't post the same thing again, it will just get closed and deleted again and eventually you'll get banned from asking new questions.

Comment: Wasn't going to repost it, don't worry :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your question text.

> Why would a Web Developer choose Mac Os over Windows/Linux? My own
>   reasoning to switch is so I'd have "best of both wordls", namely from
>   Windows and Linux. My points are relevant to our working environment
>   (namely things like Lync, Skype) What points could I offer to the
>   people making the final decision to nudge them towards Mac? Here's
>   what I've thought so far (will update with good points from replies):
>
> - Adobe Creative Suite runs on Mac *vs. Linux*
>
>   - Some web design can be offloaded from our designer to developer
>       *vs. Linux*
>   - Gimp and other freeware just doesn't work as well
> - Microsoft Office runs on Mac *vs. Linux*
> - Microsoft Lync runs on Mac *vs. Linunx*
> - Skype isn't stuck on 2.2 beta on Mac *vs. Linux*
> - Mac runs virtual Linux servers easily and without a hazzle *vs.
>     Windows*
>
>   - Wamp is Wamp. It's not a clone of the live environment, and never
>       will be. *vs. Windows*
> - Mac has a terminal (Putty is just so crude, even PuttyTerminal
>     isn't good enough) *vs.  Windows*
>
>   - Certain tasks are faster and easier to do in commandline *vs.
>       Windows*
> - Built in SSH *vs. Windows*
> - Mac supports fuse (mounting remote developement servers to appear
>     locally) *vs. Windows*
>
>   - No WinSCP hanging in the middle prompting to supply password at
>       odd times *vs. Windows*
> - More choices for Development IDE's *vs. Linux/Windows*
>
>   - Comfortable IDE contributes towards more efficient work *vs.
>       Linux/Windows*
>
> edit: For those voting close based on:
>
> *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.* Asking for points,
>   supplying examples - this is quite clear.
>
> *This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad.* It's
>   quite specific, with a clear reasoning why it's being asked and the
>   information is highly useful for any other in the same situation.
>
> *This question isr rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its
>   current form*. While true, it would be hard to pick the "correct"
>   answer as it's subjective, questions still commonly have multiple
>   right answers and the best answer is usually selected as the correct
>   answer.
>
> That said it's quite interesting to see upvotes and downvotes, and
>   people favoriting the question, but the thread still most likely
>   getting closed. :)

Comment: Greatly appreciated, I'll be back to accept later, 9 more min and gotta leave work now. :)

Answer (score 7):

There are ways to get the text, including emailing the team (team@stackoverflow.com), asking a 10k or mod, using the [deleted question viewer](https://stackapps.com/questions/2505/stack-exchange-deleted-question-viewer), or gaining 10k yourself, but your post was closed and deleted for a reason.

Where do you want to ask this?  There's nowhere on the Stack Exchange network where contentious questions like this have a home.  With some effort, it might be possible to work it into a [good subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) question.  However, it is not ready to be copied anywhere except your local hard drive yet.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I implied I would be posting this over at SE - instead, the question found it's home on a web development forum, where it is better suited as it's more of a discussion anyway. :)

Thanks for the link to DQV, might come in handy later on.